# How far does active directory scale?

Tags: active-directory

OK this may be a bit like asking "how long is a piece of string?" - but, how far does AD scale?  When should you do a transition to ADFS?  Say I have 10 million users, how much should it scale by?  What type of architecture would suit this best?

Sorry, I know this is very open ended but if anyone has any useful links that would be great.  Is it possible to setup custom roles also?  Like "Office Admin" which can edit users and "Company Admin" which can edit Office Admin and below etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [Planning an Active Directory Deployment Project](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756178%28WS.10%29.aspx) on Microsoft Web site, [specialy Active Directory Maximum Limits - Scalability](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/active-directory-maximum-limits-scalability%28WS.10%29.aspx).